# In Laravel 5.7 app make validation with tinyMCE editor

Tags: validation, laravel-5, tinymce

In my Laravel 5.7 application I use laravel-jsvalidation plugin( https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/wiki/Basic-Usage )
and it worked ok,
I needed to including textarea input as tinyMCE editor and to use i with validation and I implemented it with 2 textarea inputs :

```
<div class="form-row mb-3 {{ in_array('description', $errorFieldsArray) ? 'validation_error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <span style="display: inline;">
            {{ Form::textarea('description', isset($vote->description) ? $vote->description : '', [   "class"=>"form-control editable_field textarea_input ", "rows"=>"0", "cols"=> 120, "id"=>"description", "autocomplete"=>"off", "style"=>"width:0; height:0" ] ) }}
        </span>
        {{ Form::textarea('description_container', isset($vote->description) ? $vote->description : '', [   "class"=>"form-control editable_field textarea_input ", "rows"=>"5", "cols"=> 120,  "id"=>"description_container", "autocomplete"=>"off"  ] ) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

where 1st textarea is for form submitting, as entered content is copied into it from 2nd textarea, which is used as
tinyMCE editor.
In tinyMCE definition I added rows:

```
 setup: function (editor) {
     editor.on('change', function () {
         var current_context= tinymce.get(by_selector_container).getContent()
         $('#' + by_selector).html( current_context );
     });
 },
```

where by_selector_container and by_selector are names of these textarea inputs. It works, but the only problem that on page I can see 1st textarea input, 
despite I try to hide it setting wight/height in 0 in style of my code above, but anyway I still see small textarea input : https://i.stack.imgur.com/78ncE.jpg

I tried in declaration of the 1st textarea input to set

```
"style"=>"display:none"
```

Than textarea input was hidden but validation does not work at all.

How to hide it this small textarea input with validation working?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at this page online http://votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/vote/create - credetials are provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try style:

```
visibility: hidden ;
```